# Mule VM Queue thread configuration

Tags: mule

[image]

I am trying to understand how to fine tune the threading profiles in Mule using 3.5 CE

**Flow1**

Fetch files from an FTP endpoint and pool it a VM queue.

**Flow 2**

Reads from the above VM queue with transaction enabled and do some business logic processing.

---

I was assuming that Flow 2 will be executed in multiple threads based on the VM connector thread configuration. But what I notice is that the second flow is always using 4 threads only to execute it in parallel.  Have tried configuring default threading profile and it doesnt make any difference either. Please let me know what I am missing. Any help is appreciated

**Sample VM connector configuration**

```
  <vm:connector name="ITS_VM" validateConnections="true"   >
    <receiver-threading-profile  maxThreadsIdle="30" maxBufferSize="5000" maxThreadsActive="40"/>
    <dispatcher-threading-profile maxThreadsIdle="30" maxBufferSize="5000" maxThreadsActive="40"/>
     <vm:queue-profile  maxOutstandingMessages="500">
         </vm:queue-profile>
    </vm:connector>
```

***Sample Default configuration***

```
<configuration >
    <default-threading-profile  maxThreadsIdle="30" maxBufferSize="5000" maxThreadsActive="40" />
    <default-dispatcher-threading-profile maxThreadsIdle="30" maxBufferSize="5000" maxThreadsActive="40"/>
    <default-receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsIdle="30" maxBufferSize="5000" maxThreadsActive="40" />
        </configuration>
```

***Console Log*****

```
15:26:13,728 [FetchFiles_Flow.stage1.02] INFO Queued 1 file
15:26:13,797 [ITS_VM.receiver.02] INFO ---------------------------Processing 1 file
15:26:14,114 [FetchFiles_Flow.stage1.03] INFO Queued 1 file
15:26:14,146 [ITS_VM.receiver.03] INFO ---------------------------Processing 1 file
15:26:14,512 [FetchFiles_Flow.stage1.04] INFO Queued 1 file
15:26:14,547 [ITS_VM.receiver.04] INFO--------------------------- Processing 1 file
15:26:14,947 [FetchFiles_Flow.stage1.05] INFO Queued 1 file
15:26:15,000 [ITS_VM.receiver.01] INFO--------------------------- Processing 1 file
15:26:15,349 [FetchFiles_Flow.stage1.06] INFO Queued 1 file
15:26:15,740 [FetchFiles_Flow.stage1.07] INFO Queued 1 file
15:26:16,122 [FetchFiles_Flow.stage1.08] INFO Queued 1 file
15:26:16,510 [FetchFiles_Flow.stage1.09] INFO Queued 1 file
15:26:16,892 [FetchFiles_Flow.stage1.10] INFO Queued 1 file
15:26:17,272 [FetchFiles_Flow.stage1.11] INFO Queued 1 file
15:26:17,646 [FetchFiles_Flow.stage1.12] INFO Queued 1 file
15:26:18,017 [FetchFiles_Flow.stage1.13] INFO Queued 1 file
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After debugging the source code from Mule jars I figured out I need to also set the number of consumers polling the VM queue.

I got this working by setting the numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers on vm:connector  to a higher number. The default is 4 and that was why I was seeing 4 parallel threads only.

It works fine now. Hope this would be useful for someone

`<vm:connector name="ITS_VM" validateConnections="true" createMultipleTransactedReceivers="true" numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers="30"` >

A related post can be found here
http://ricston.com/blog/mule-jms-consumers-max-threads-active/

Comment: I just want to express the [Mule documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/configuring-a-transport) has serious deficiencies in this area.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [this](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Tuning+Performance) page in documentation, there you will find that:

> A Mule ESB application is a collaboration of a set of flows.
>   Conceptually, messages are processed by flows in three stages:
>
> 1. The message being received by the inbound connector
> 2. The message being processed
> 3. The message being sent via an outbound connector

And then:

> Tuning performance in Mule involves analyzing and improving these
>   three stages for each flow. You can start by applying the same tuning
>   approach to all flows and then further customize the tuning for each
>   flow as needed.

You can read **Calculating Threads** section to learn how to understand what you need.

Regards.