# Can I set max limit of files to be processed on single poll?

Tags: java, mule, sftp

I have configured a **sftp:inbound-endpoint** which polls files from an SFTP server, however, occasionally, there are lots of files which are polled at the same time (about 500) and it causes big slowdowns on the processing application.

Here is my code:

```xml
<sftp:inbound-endpoint 
     sizeCheckWaitTime="${sizeCheckWaitTime}" 
     connector-ref="ImportInformationStatusSFTP"
     host="${sftp.host}"
     port="${sftp.port}"
     path="${sftp.path}"
     user="${sftp.user}"
     password="${sftp.password}"
     responseTimeout="${sftp.responseTimeout}"
     archiveDir="${mule.archiveDir}${sftp.archiveDir}"
     archiveTempReceivingDir="${sftpconnector.archiveTempReceivingDir}"
     archiveTempSendingDir="${sftpconnector.archiveTempSendingDir}"
     tempDir="${sftp.tempDir}" 
     doc:name="SFTP"
     pollingFrequency="${sftp.poll.frequency}">
     <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="*.xml"/>
</sftp:inbound-endpoint>
```

Is there a way to set a limit on the number of files polled?

Comment: Can you add some of the code that does the polling so that we might be able to better help you out.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to do this. An alternative for this particular use case could be to refactor the flow to send the files to a VM queue instead of processing them directly. The VM queue consumption concurrency [can be limited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25924805/721855) unlike the SFTP connector.